# How to count the number of occurrences of semi-duplicate rows and make the count a new column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[4, 4, 1, 5, 1, 1],
                   'B':[2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2],
                   'C':[1, 1, 3, 5, 3, 3],
                   'D':['q', 'e', 'r', 'y', 'u',' w']})
```

which looks like

```
    A   B   C   D
0   4   2   1   q
1   4   2   1   e
2   1   2   3   r
3   5   5   5   y
4   1   2   3   u
5   1   2   3   w
```

I would like to add a new column that is the count of duplicate rows, with respect to only the columns A, B, and C. This would look like

```
    A   B   C   D   Count
0   4   2   1   q   2
1   4   2   1   e   2
2   1   2   3   r   3
3   5   5   5   y   1
4   1   2   3   u   3
5   1   2   3   w   3
```

I'm guessing this will be something like df.groupby(['A','B','C']).size() but I am unsure how to map the values back to the new 'Count' column. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do `transform`

```
df['Count'] = df.groupby(['A','B','C']).D.transform('count')
df['Count']
0    2
1    2
2    3
3    1
4    3
5    3
Name: Count, dtype: int64
```